# Banana Pi M3 vs Asus Tinker Board

Tags: mini-pc

I'm a little unsure what board to buy here. The Banana Pi M3 seems to have a faster CPU, with eight cores compared to a quad core on the Asus tinker board. I haven't been able to find a comparison between the two performance wise.

Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe even tell the difference if you happen to have both boards?

Comment: You might get better results if you list your requirements and let us help you pick the correct board for your needs. Also let us know what you will be using the board for to help us narrow it down.